# Get an element from a linked list in c++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I am trying to return the data inside a linked list to store it in a variable or directly using it inside another function but I don't exactly know how to implement that.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <class Object>
struct node{

    Object data;
    node *next;

};
template <class Object>
class list{

private:
    node<Object> *head, *tail;
public:
    list(){
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }

    void display(){

        node<Object> *temp=new node<Object>;
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"              ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }

    void createnode(Object value){
        node<Object> *temp=new node<Object>;
        temp->data=value;
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){

            head=temp;
            tail=temp;
            temp=NULL;

        }else{

            tail->next=temp;
            tail=temp;

        }
    }

    void insert_start(Object value){

        node<Object> *temp=new node<Object>;
        temp->data=value;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;

    }

    node<Object> GetNth(){
        node<Object> *current = head;

        while(current != NULL)
            if(current->next == NULL){
                return current->data;
            }


    }

    void delete_last(){

        node<Object> *current=new node<Object>;
        node<Object> *previous=new node<Object>;
        current=head;
        while(current->next!=NULL){

            previous=current;
            current=current->next;

        }
        tail=previous;
        previous->next=NULL;
        delete current;

    }

};

int main(){

        ifstream ifile;
        ifile.open( "input.txt" );

        char word[300];
        ifile >> word;

        char* token = strtok( word, "," );
        list<string> kids;
        list<string> tasks;

        while ( token != NULL ) {
            kids.createnode(token);
            token = strtok( NULL, "," );
        }

        ifile >> word;
        token = strtok(word, ",");

        while (token != NULL) {
            tasks.createnode(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }

        int days;
        cout << "Enter the number of days: ";
        cin >> days;

        tasks.display();

        cout << endl;

        int first = 0;
        string nextTask;

        while(first < days){
            cout << "Day " << first + 1 << "            ";
            kids.display();
            kids.insert_start(kids.GetNth());
            kids.delete_last();
            first++;
        }

        return 0;

}
```

The purpose of this program is to assign different tasks to each kid depending on the day. I am currently having trouble with the getNth function it would be great if anyone can help me out. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Do not call your class `list`.  There already is a `std::list` in C++.

Comment: Also, `main` and any other users of the linked list class shouldn't know anything about `node` -- that is an implementation detail of the list.  The proper way would be an `add` function that takes a value by reference.  The `GetNth` should return a value, etc.  The concept of `node` should not be exposed to the outside -- let the list class itself do the node handling.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie calling it `list` would be just fine if only they didn't `using namespace std`.

Comment: *I am currently having trouble with the getNth function* -- You didn't state the exact trouble you're having.  There are issues with the function, but you need to state the issue that you're seeing now and having trouble with.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by making 'node' not exposed to the outside. Do you mean I should try making it into a class instead of a struct or just adding it into the 'LinkedList' class?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the issue that I'm having is that I dont understand how to use it exactly to retrieve the value inside that specific node to use it in another function or store it in a variable.

Comment: @MaqAlmulla -- Why should `main` know about nodes?  All it needs to know is that it uses a linked list and the list holds values.  Why must `main` know the internals of the list?  `main` puts values in the list, it gets values out of the list, not `nodes`.  The `GetNth` function should *not* be returning nodes.  It should be returning a value that is stored at the Nth node.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], it summarizes a few comments others had in response to your question. Also, read [mcve]. In this case, you should strip the whole `template` stuff (use a single type) and the input from a file (use hardcoded data) to get closer to an MCVE.

Comment: @MaqAlmulla `node<Object> GetNth()` -- This is the concern.  This should be `Object GetNth()` or `Object& GetNth()`.  Otherwise you put `main` into the business of knowing what a `node` is, and all `main` should know is the `Object` it stored in the list.  Also, what do you return if `N` is greater than the number of items in the list?

Comment: You should compare your implementation with the plethora of implementations already on the internet.  Search the internet for "c++ linked list eample".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have trouble because the GetNth() doesn't return value if the list is empty.

```
node<Object> GetNth(){
    node<Object> *current = head;

    while(current != NULL)
        if(current->next == NULL){
            return current->data;
        }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a std::list, it is already included in C++. You can use `at` to aceess the nth element.

Comment: There is no `at()` member function for `std::list`.  To get to the nth element, use `std::next(list.begin(), n);` to return an iterator to element `n`.

Comment: Yes, that is right. The function at() is in QList. Lists are not so interesting for random access though.